# CruiseControl install

Tags: windows-xp, cruisecontrol.net

I just have an XP machine, and i want to play around using CC.NET.

Would i be able to install it and get it working in XSP with IIS 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do everything on a single machine. I have a similar setup currently running on my machine.

You don't even need to configure the dashboard in this case. It works out of the box with a local CCNet server.

The only issue I had was that I had to switch the dashboard to the ClassicAppPool in IIS. [Here](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/02/tips-tricks-how-to-change-app-pool.html)'s a blog post on how to do that.